# Mysql query to find sum of fields with same column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id |  invent_id         |   order
 1 | 95948214           | 70
 2 | 46018572           | 30
 3 | 46018572           | 20
 4 | 46018572           | 50
 5 | 36025764           | 60
 6 | 36025764           | 70
 7 | 95948214           | 80
 8 | 95948214           | 90
```

I want get the sum of order qty with same invent id

That is the want the result like this

```
   |  invent_id         |   order
   | 95948214           | 240
   | 46018572           | 100
   | 36025764           | 130
```

how can we write the mysql query

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make use of Aggregate function `SUM` and grouped them according to `invent_id`.

```
SELECT invent_id, SUM(`order`) `Order`
FROM tableName
GROUP BY invent_ID
```

**[GROUP BY clause](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)**

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dc41/4)

Comment: No,this is not possible there is a db error while executing the query

Comment: did you escape the column name `order`?

Comment: @ArjunanArjun See the reason for your error in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dc41/3)

Comment: I have write the query like this                                SELECT invent_id,SUM(order_qty) order FROM `projects_invents_orders` WHERE GROUP BY invent_id    but there is error

Comment: you should escape `order` using backtick even though it's an alias.

Comment: i bet this is the error you are seeing `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use...`

Comment: @hims056 thanks for the modification. really appreciate it. :D