# MySQL query to get the sum of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I need to get the sum of column with two conditions.i.e

example:

```
Dos        Insurance   bill_amount
29/11/14    LIC        200
29/11/14    Medicare        300
29/11/14    Selfpay        300
29/11/14    Medicare        400
29/11/14    aetna        900
29/11/14    selfpay       900
29/11/14    Prestige        100
29/11/14    LIC        500
```

I need the write the query so that I get the view as

```
dos      Total_amount selfpay

29/11/14 2400           1200
```

Please guide me to wite query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql query to find sum of fields with same column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399479/mysql-query-to-find-sum-of-fields-with-same-column-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Dos, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Insurance != 'Selfpay' THEN bill_amount ELSE 0 END) Total_amount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Insurance = 'Selfpay' THEN bill_amount ELSE 0 END) selfpay 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY Dos;
```